# Python SQL date diff query

Tags: python, datediff

I am writing a program to find out the differences between todays date and a date of birth. I am trying to use Date Diff to get their age but the method
keeps returning this message
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

```
def workoutage():
    print ("Current date and time: " , datetime.datetime.now())

    print ("Or like this: " ,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print("the date today is ", today)
    con =  lite.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()
    ' - DateofBirth ) from Pupils"

    ageQuery = "SELECT pupils.dateofBirth DATEDIFF(day,  '"+today+", 
    pupils.dateofBirth) AS NumberOfDays from Pupils"""
    cur.execute(ageQuery)
    ageQueryList = cur.fetchall()
    showList(ageQueryList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your SQL.

The error message is pretty explicit. Parser encountered `(` when it was expecting something else, and there is only one `(` in your query.

A `select` statement is `select column, column, ...` so you need a comma after `pupils.dateofBirth`.